# Total Number of Certificates issued / revoked

Tags: active-directory, certificate, ad-certificate-services

Currently using Active Directory Certificate Services. Is it possible to find out the total number of certificates that have been published and revoked up till today, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Manual (non-script)

1. In Active Directory Certificate Services console, right-click **Revoked Certificates**, select **Export List...** and save the file.
2. Open file in Notepad
3. Make sure you have **Format - Word Wrap** option turned off
4. Make sure you have **View - Status Bar** option turned on
5. Press **Ctrl+End** to go to the end of the file and position your cursor on last line with text
6. Check Notepad status bar for line number
7. Subtract one from the number since first line always contains column numes

### CMD script

```
certutil -view -restrict "Disposition=20" -out SerialNumber csv | find "Serial Number" /V /C
```

Here are `Disposition` values:

- 8 request is being processed
- 9 request is taken under submission
- 12 certificate is an archived foreign certificate
- 15 certificate is a CA certificate
- 16 parent CA certificates of the CA certificate
- 17 certificate is a key recovery agent certificate
- 20 certificate was issued
- 21 certificate is revoked
- 30 certificate request failed
- 31 certificate request is denied

Note: script tested only on Windows Server 2008 R2